# Entity Framework not saving changes; db context used, entity state set to modified

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Once again, I have a very simple situation that I would expect to work fine, and it's not, and I am not seeing what's wrong.

```
    // visit all the sizegroups and update their visible field
    foreach (var sizeGroup in db.SizeGroups) {
        if (checkedSizeGroups.Contains(sizeGroup.Id)) {
            sizeGroup.Visible = true;
        }
        else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SizeGroup hidden: " + sizeGroup.Id.ToString());
            sizeGroup.Visible = false;
        }
        db.Entry(sizeGroup).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
```

The debug output is showing that certain sizegroup id's should have their Visibility bit column getting set to 0, but when I look in the database, they're still all 1.

Comment: `int x=db.SaveChanges();` what's the value of x?

Comment: due to `foreach`  last value of loop will be save

Comment: @tinka I don't think that's accurate

Comment: Add: `db.Database.Log = Console.Write` before your `db.SaveChanges();` and see what SQL is getting generated.

Comment: I bet you're checking the wrong database.

Comment: The database is the same one that's being used to populate the view after saving changes, and the refreshed view is showing all the checkboxes checked.

Comment: db result is 165.. what does that mean?

Comment: You're right. I was looking at the wrong database. There are 165 rows in the sizegroups table in my dev db. This project is configured to hit the dev db while in debug mode. And looking at that db, this code is working correctly. So it's my view code that isn't working. Maybe I should delete this question.